# jQuery File Upload crashing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jquery-filedrop](http://www.github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) and python/flask to upload files to an uploads folder on my server.

However whenever I select a large file (~80MB+) the browser tab (chrome) instantly crashes.

Looking into [the code](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop/blob/master/jquery.filedrop.js) and from the readme it seems to use HTML5 FileReader() to handle the file upload.

If I take a small chunk of the file by changing [these lines](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop/blob/master/jquery.filedrop.js#L322-L326):

```
reader.onloadend = !opts.beforeSend ? send : function (e) {
      opts.beforeSend(files[fileIndex], fileIndex, function () { send(e); });
};

reader.readAsDataURL(files[fileIndex]);
```

to

```
reader.onloadend = !opts.beforeSend ? send : function (e) {
      opts.beforeSend(files[fileIndex].slice(0, 1048576), fileIndex, function () { send(e); });
};

reader.readAsDataURL(files[fileIndex].slice(0, 1048576));
```

Then I can get it to run without an error by only uploading 1MB from each file, so I'm guessing it's a memory issue when the full file is read in.

How could I set it up to loop through small chunks of the file and upload them separately? Or, are there any better workarounds?

Comment: http://kongaraju.blogspot.in/2012/07/large-file-upload-more-than-1gb-using.html try this out, you can easily understand

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Chrome crashes if you are running the loops with heavy objects. The best thing you can do use Webworkers to process files and then read the chucks.

Resources

- [File APIs HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)
- [Webworkers HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

If using HTML5 FileReader(), then the `file` option has a `slice` method that you can use.

`var blob = file.slice(startingByte, endindByte);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);`

For more information: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Thanks, but in the example I gave I used slice to read in a sample of the file, I'm wondering if it's possible to have jquery-filedrop read the files slice by slice and upload each slice, then re-combine them. I have used a basic file input form before and that seemed to work with large files, but for some reason this crashes.